# What to do if Cassandra reports failure but did a partial write?

Tags: transactions, cassandra, acid

Cassandra does not guarantee atomic behavior so there is a slight chance that one replica fails but other replica do persist the change.

Are there any information how to defend against this and what to do in order to heal it if it happens? Does Cassandra heal itself in that regard?

[Update]

I specially focus on the case where you send a write request to lets say all replica and only one replica fails with a write error. The node failing with the write is still alive and operational. According to the Cassandra documentation the write request will return a failure even the two other (if you have a replication factor of 3) succeeded.

According to the documentation in this case two replica has changed and one remains original. There was stated that in this case its a non-consistent state since the other two will not be able to roll back any change written.

So the question goes how can one defend against that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cassandra a timeout such as this is not considered a failure.  See [this blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure) describing how Cassandra handles different conditions when it comes to writes:

> Remember that for writes, a timeout is not a failure.
>
> How can we say that since we don’t know what happened before the replica failed? The coordinator can force the results towards either the pre-update or post-update state. This is what Cassandra does with hinted handoff.
>
> ...the coordinator stores the update locally, and will re-send it to the failed replica when it recovers, thus forcing it to the post-update state that the client wanted originally.

So to answer your question, yes cassandra will heal itself using hinted handoff, and when that process fails (i.e. max_hint_window_in_ms exceeded before replica becomes online), a repair should get things into a consistent state.  This is one reason why it is recommended to run repairs regularly.

[This article](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_hh_c.html) explains hinted handoff in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the info you are correct. But I specially aim to the write error while the replica remains intact. So two nodes have changed but one remains in the old state. So how is that solved?

Comment: Hinted handoffs, repairs and read repairs will solve this issue.  Cassandra uses timestamps on write and uses a concept called 'last write wins', so the writes with the newest timestamps will be considered the correct ones.

Comment: Blog post explaining how cassandra handles this by using timestamps on columns: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/why-cassandra-doesnt-need-vector-clocks

Comment: It is possible that if you are querying with a reduced Consistency Level with Reads vs. Writes you can get inconsistent data, that is why it is important to use the same consistency levels for reads and writes, unless you don't mind temporarily inconsistent data.

Comment: Or I go with using ALL on write and use one on read but if I use quorum on write and read I am also save right?

Comment: Correct, you will be safe with a CL of QUORUM for reads and writes as in order for the read to succeed the data needs to be consistent within a quorum of the nodes.  To amend my previous comment, if you use a CL of ONE for both reads and writes you could get inconsistent data as well. So i suppose its important to use QUORUM if you for reads if you want consistent data.

Comment: Make sure the condition (Read_Consistency_number + Write_Consistency_number >= Number_of_nodes_in_cluster) is met, the consistent data is guaranteed.

Comment: @PrabuSoundarRajan what numbers (e.g. Read_Consistency_number) is assigned to what consistency?